# How to make builds fail when TFS fails to unshelve a shelveset

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Okay, so my first question is which imbecil thought it would be a good idea not to fail the build when **validate shelveset** build fails to unshelve the shelveset which it is supposed to validate?

Also, if unshelving the shelvset caused a merge conflict, why doesn't the system fail the build as well?

Now, I have to wait an hour and a half for the build to finish, half an hour to copy the files and additional 15 minutes of scratching my head before I finally realize that the build has silently failed but ignored that fact.

In the first case, there is a line in the log:

`No changes unshelved.`

In the second case, lines of this form can be found:

`Conflict: There were changes committed between the unshelved version and original workspace version of <filepath>`

So, I though, I'll just add a build step that looks for those lines in the log and fails the build if it finds them, but all logs are stored in the TFS database, so I don't really have access to those.

Does anyone know how do I make the pain of working with TFS duller and make it fail in these cases?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? What build system? XAML? Classic JSON?

Comment: Good point, I could have added that. It's the last version that can be self hosted without any cloud components, I'm gonna have to check which one exactly Monday. I use the built in pipeline editor, I believe I've seen "show as JSON" button or something similar, so I'm going to go with JSON.

Comment: The last version you can self-host without any cloud components is Azure DevOps Server 2022 (i.e. the most recent version), so you could literally be running any of the following: 2015, 2017, 2018, 2020, or 2022. It's a huge swath of possibilities.

Comment: Is this a gated checkin build? Is exclusive checkout enabled or are multiple checkouts enabled? Are you working with a version so old that it is from before shelveset merges were supported?

Comment: Okay, I have access to info you're asking now. We're using Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2. It's a regular build with selected shelveset, it's not a gated checkin build, we're not using that feature at all.
All I want is for the shelvsed validation build to fail if it fails to validate a shelvset, either because it can't unshelve it or because it can't merge it.
Note that our workspaces are quite large, so I've had to set build.useserverworkspaces to true to save on space on our build agents.